# Burninate the [internal] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A huge (~450) list of questions is tagged as [internal](/questions/tagged/internal), but they have little in common. For example, there are questions about:

- internal storage
- internal arrays
- internal errors
- internal classes
- internal IPs
- internal links
- etc.

Probably it should be burninated, since it doesn't help in searching as it stands.

Comment: Sounds like it should be handled like any other meta tag

Comment: Perhaps some, but not all. [Internal is actually a C# keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.90).aspx), so please, if you let loose with the fiah, spare the questions which are tagged with both internal and c# as it has context there.